# jquery datepicker- month selection (no dropdowns)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, calendarextender

i use with `jquery datepicker` (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-dialog)

I want to have the option to choose the months and years.
I define this:

```
 $("input").datepicker({  
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
        });
```

But I really hate the dropdowns  of `datepicker`.
I want to have the option to choose the months and years as in `ajaxToolkit: CalendarExtender`
[image]

It is possible??

Comment: I don't think jQuery UI's datepicker has that view, but maybe you'd want to take a look at this other plugin [Datepicker for Bootstrap](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Comment: thank you!!! but i want use jQuery UI's, Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

As @koala_dev mentioned, you can achieve it using **Datepicker for Bootstrap**.

**Updated:**

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  format: " m-yyyy",
  viewMode: "months",
  minViewMode: "months"
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge the external link in the fiddle were expired.  Now I have fixed with cdns.  Check out